# Swagger code generation not deterministic

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

Lets say there are two RestControllers in my SpringBoot backend which both have a method/endpoint called `getData()`:

*PersonController.java*

```
@GetMapping("/person/data")
public ResponseEntity<String> getData() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Person Data");
}
```

*PetController.java*

```
@GetMapping("/pet/data")
public ResponseEntity<String> getData() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Pet Data");
}
```

Swagger now generates services in the frontend with matching methods, which (should) look something like this:

*personController.service.ts*

```
public getData(observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false ): Observable<any> {

    ...

    return this.httpClient.request<string>('get',`${this.basePath}/person/data`,
        {
            ...
        }
    );
}
```

*petController.service.ts*

```
public getData(observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false ): Observable<any> {

    ...

    return this.httpClient.request<string>('get',`${this.basePath}/pet/data`,
        {
            ...
        }
    );
}
```

But in fact, swagger does not create both methods as `getData(...)` and rather names the second created method `getData1(...)`. This is weird, because the names would not collide, but where it stops being weird and starts being really annoying is when swagger decides to randomly switch which method gets extended with `1` and which not.

This leads to finding yourself having errors like the following thoughout the whole code:

```
error TS2551: Property 'getData1' does not exist on type 'PersonControllerService'. Did you mean 'getData'?
error TS2551: Property 'getData' does not exist on type 'PetControllerService'. Did you mean 'getData1'?
```

Is there a way to prevent swagger from unnecessarily extending the methods names in the first place?
If not, is there a solution to getting at least the same results with each run?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What TypeScript code generator do you use - Swagger Codegen, OpenAPI Generator, [openapi-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-typescript), something else? How are the `/person/data` and `/pet/data` endpoints defined in the OpenAPI YAML/JSON file generated from your Java Spring code?

Comment: Im using swagger codegen
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen